# Excel adding unwanted cells to formula

Tags: excel, formula

I've been using Excel for quite a long time & I've never noticed this issue before. Someone at work asked me & I thought it must be a simple fix, but I'm stumped.

Let's start with `A1:F1` being blanks, and `G1` being `=SUM(A1:C1)`  Pretty standard add the values. I only want `G1` to sum the first 3 cells in Row1, even though there will be values in the others.

When I add values into cells `A1:C1`, no problem. As soon as I add a value to `D1` the formula in G1 auto magically "fixes" itself to `=SUM(A1:D1)`. Then a value in `E1` changes the formula to `=SUM(A1:E1)`. And so on... I need the formula to only sum A1:C1 regardles of the other values.

So I spent the usual 15-20 minutes looking all over the ribbons and options, and another 15-20 on the interwebs, but here I am. Hope it's not something stoopid that I missed and I feel like a dummy.

Comment: So here's a potential dumb work around, but not the fix i would like. If you fill the cells in from left to right, A1 to F1 the problem happens. If you fill in the cells out of sequence, it doesn't happen. Makes sense, breaking the "Excel knows best" logic.

Comment: 2010, fortunately...

Comment: Does the formula `=SUM(A1:$C$1)` work?

Comment: No luck with adding $. First thing I tried.

Comment: Is the data in a table, perhaps?

Comment: As I did receive a solution it appears that this was a correct forum for this question. I'm sorry for wasting your invaluable time on my misplaced bootless errand. Perhaps next time you should expend your precious efforts on something more constructive, versus a smug comment in the guise of "helpful advice".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winner Winner Chicken Dinner.

pnut solves it. "Uncheck Extend data range formats and formulas."

File> Options> Advanced > Uncheck Extend data range formats and formulas

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do that, but you could just put `=SUM(A1+B1+C1)` in `G1` instead and then it won't do that

Comment: This would work on a small scale, which is my case. But A1:JK1 many times over wouldn't be so much fun.